# No feedback if mount command fails when executed with popen() function

Tags: c++, linux, popen, mount

When executing the linux command "mount", with invalid parameters and execute it with the popen() function in my C++ code. The output is empty. I'm expecting an error like this: "mount: mount point test does not exist"

Here is the code that should generate some errors as 'test' doesn't exist:

```
FILE *file;
char data[512];
if((file = popen("mount test test", "r")))
{
    while(fgets(data, sizeof(data), file)!=NULL)
    {
         printf("%s", data);
    }
    pclose(file);
}
```

data array is empty. But when I replace the command "mount test test" with "date" the data array gets filled with the following: "Wed Jan  4 08:20:23 EST 2017".

Thanks if any of you have ideas.

Comment: The problem is that `popen` only reads the standard output (`stdout`) of the child process, not the standard error (`stderr`). If you need to read `stderr` and/or get the exit status (which is a safer bet than reading and parsing output) then you need to implement your own popen-like function using `fork`, `exec`, `pipe`, `dup` (or `dup2`) and `wait`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By looking for more info following your answer I stumbled on this. As I only care about (stderr) and not about (stdout). I tried `popen("mount test test 2>&1 >/dev/null", "r")` and it works fine. I get the error.

Comment: Note that there is a direct mount() function you can call (see "man 2 mount" for details) which might be a better approach that spawning a child process with popen().